# U-Boot env from Linux WITHOUT MTD

Tags: filesystems, u-boot

I'm trying to access U-Boot environment from Linux. It seems that there is only one tool to achieve that : `fw_printenv/fw_setenv`.

But those tools are only usable on a MTD with UBIFS, and I'm running on a more "classical" file system (FAT for U-Boot, ext4 for Linux). I tried to find a format spec for `U-Boot env` file, unsuccessfully.

Do you guys have an idea of how I could get/set those U-Boot variables from my Linux without MTD/UBI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I couldn't make those utils work, I finally decided to create my own.
I wrote it as a Python module : [U-Boot-env-editor](https://github.com/PinkPR/U-Boot-env-editor)

I hope it will be useful for some of you :)

Answer (score 1):

The current [fw_env.config](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=tools/env/fw_env.config;h=7916ebdb1f6d1836c49d9374cf4ebfac2bcf0009;hb=HEAD) file has an example of how to read the environment from a file on FAT (or any other filesystem, really) as well as from being written directly to the sectors on SD/etc.

Comment: How thank you very much ! It's the first example I've seen that has a non-MTD example ! I'll try it right now.